# SAPUI5: DatePicker chosen Date, disabled the Display of the Date in the InputField

Tags: javascript, datepicker, sapui5, display

As the Title states. The `Datepicker` does consist of two Elements: the Input Field and the Picking of Date(look at the Image below)

[image: Datepicker]

You can set the Date that you would want manually, by directly accessing the ID of the `DatePicker` with `setDateValue()` and it will be automatically displayed in the Input Field.

Now I want to set the Date that I want but for it to not be displayed within the Input field.

The thing is that I found was `setVisible(false)` - however this just makes the whole field disappear. What I want is simply to disable the display of the chosen date. How can I make it happen?

Comment: You can use the [Custom Data - Attaching Data Objects to Controls](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.7/docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [Custom Data - Attaching Data Objects to Controls](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/91/f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm?no_cache=true)

To use custom data you need to use the following namespace for the respective attributes:

```
myNamespace="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1"
```

**XML view**

In XML view you need to include the **namespace** also need to use `app:mySuperExtraData="CUSTTOM DATA"` to attach custom data to the control.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" controllerName="my.own.controller"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
     <Button text="Click" app:mySuperExtraData="just great"></Button>
</mvc:View>
```

**Use with Data Binding**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" controllerName="my.own.controller" 
           xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
     <Button text="Click" app:coords="{data}" press="alertCoordinates"></Button>
</mvc:View>
```

**JS view**

By using `data()` we can attach data objects to controls.

```
myButton.data("myData", "Hello");
```

**Retrieve custom data**

```
myButton.data("myData")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I am sure that this works, however is there a more simpler way?

Comment: As per my knowledge this is the simplest way, just by attaching the custom data to the control itself and also it is easy way to get the attached custom data.